# Is a question about implementation and usability appropriate to SO? Some other SE site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm working on an iOS photo app and need to decide between several methods of capturing and managing the photos. I'm not having code issues per se (though I will likely have a few code related questions depending on the implementation, which might help decide on *which* implementation to adopt).

My specific questions right now pertain to usability and iOS user expectations, along with Apple guidelines and restrictions. The opinions and perspective of more experienced developers would be helpful

I *think* the question is of sufficient general interest but since it is not primarily coding specific, maybe not. At any rate, I thought I would ask.

Comment: Probably Programmer.SE

Comment: The Usability questions could go to [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Don't be afraid to split up your questions across the network. That's better than getting them deleted or closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, I would lean towards the [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) SE for the usability questions, and then for questions regarding how to implement a specific task I would think SO would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

On gut instinct I would say the Apple SE, but that's for Apple proprietary hardware and software.

Perhaps if you're looking for developer help, programmers SE might be a good fit? It just seems a better fit if you're asking slightly more abstract programming/design questions. Whereas SO seems to be more if you're looking for concrete advice for how to implement a design.